# Is "What are you known for?" a Mexican idiom?

Tags: modismos

A high school friend visited with my wife a few weeks ago.  The three of us are American.  The friend has an 11-year old son that was raised in Mexico.  He is bilingual.

While the friend and my wife were chatting in another room, the son and I spent some time talking about his interests.  He let me know that that he was into scouting and video games.

Then he asked me a question that took me by surprise.  On the heels of our discussion of scouting, which I let him know I was a former Boy Scout, he asked, "What are you known for?"

I stammered for a bit, not quite sure what he meant.  I asked if he meant with regards to Boy Scouts, and he said, "Anything."  I continued by limiting the discussion to scouting.

This is a mature 11-year old, and seemingly articulate.  I am wondering if he is using a direct translation of a Spanish idiom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weird. I'm from Dominican Republic, a country where our first language is Spanish. We watch movies and soap operas and listen to music from Mexico and other Spanish-speaking countries and I think I have an idea of what it means.

Translating "What are you known for?" literally to Spanish would mean "¿Por qué eres conocido?".

It could be a question regarding "for what things people know you". Like, what is that that you do that people know you for.

If in the Boy Scout you were a good swimmer and everybody there talked about how good of a swimmer you are, then you are "known for being a good swimmer".
Like in Spanish "Me conocen por ser un buen nadador", translating that to English "I'm known to be a great swimmer".

I hoped that helps.

Answer (score 1):

"*I am wondering if he is using a direct translation of a Spanish idiom*". No, no creo que este utilizando alguna traducción directa de un modismo en español.

Lo más probable es que quisiera referirse a los distintos lemas que tienen los Scouts. ¿Por que **eres** conocido?, ¿Por qué **sois** conocidos?, "What are you known for?", puede llevar a un simple malentendido. Lo más probable es que él quisiera saber el lema que utilizabas cuando eras scout.

"*I asked if he meant with regards to Boy Scouts, and he said, "**Anything***." Al decir, "**cualquiera**", en este proceso deductivo, imagino que se refería a "**cualquiera de los lemas**" que hubiera utilizado mientras había sido Scouts, dependiendo de la unidad o unidades a las que hubieras pertenecido..

---

"I am wondering if he is using a direct translation of a Spanish idiom." No, I don't think he is using any direct translation of a Spanish idiom.

Most likely he wanted to refer to the various mottos that the Scouts have. Why are you known?, What are you known for?,(¿Por que **eres** conocido?, ¿Por qué **sois** conocidos?) "What are you known for?", can lead to a simple misunderstanding. Most likely he wanted to know the motto you used when you were a scout.

I asked if he meant with regards to Boy Scouts, and he said, "**Anything**." By saying "**any**" in this deductive process, I imagine he was referring to "whatever mottos" he had used while he had been a Scout, depending on the unit or units you had belonged to.